# How to improve page load performance of the Wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating web portal in WordPress for that I am using i-craft WordPress theme. But my website page loading very slow at initial load that is before loading of all content. Its taking 8 - 10 sec to initial load. I know this is happening due to lots php code with lots of functions and loops.
 I want to remove all unnecessary code or php file. As my website belongs to only single theme and I don't want to add post functionality etc. so which file/php code/information in database I have to remove that will helps website to load initially faster. Or is there any way to make loading very fast without removing code or files.

Comment: Run [Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), that should give you some pointers where you can cut the load time. As it is, there are just too many factors that could be affecting loading times for us to really help you.

Comment: thanks @GeoffAtkins....!

Comment: If you need help with specific factors of the Page Speed Insights suggestions, then you can ask a new question based on that specific problem, either here on SO or over at ServerFault.

Comment: 1) Find out more specifically which PHP code is going slow. If you wrote it yourself, ask here for help with fixing the particular bits of code that are a problem. If it's a third party module, ask the vendor how to improve performance, or possibly search to see if there are alternative modules you could use instead. 2) Make sure you've got WP's caching features enabled; this can have a massive performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

https://gtmetrix.com

on here you can check your site analytic report .and you want to do minify your css and js file.and also images .

Comment: I am saying my website initial speed is slow not content loading so I am not asking for fast load for content loading or css/js. I already specified in my question that is initial loading is very slow due to lots of php/mysql queries/loops so I want to remove those unnecessary codes/mysql_queries.